# How to show a map within two coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, coordinates, cllocationmanager

I want to show a map between two coordinates. I have used this code for showing a rect of map that contains both the coordinates. But both my coordinates are not shown and instead it shows the area between  that two coordinates excluding the coordinates.
what Should I do to include my two coordinates as well?

```
    let coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.53, 77.39)
    let coordinate2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.13,76.69)
    // convert them to MKMapPoint
    let p1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate (coordinate2);
    let p2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate (coordinate1);

    let mapRect = MKMapRectMake(fmin(p1.x,p2.x), fmin(p1.y,p2.y), fabs(p1.x-p2.x), fabs(p1.y-p2.y));
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it is due to autolayout. We should use `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView)` method to set for it.

```
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView) {
    // this is where visible maprect should be set
    let coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.53, 77.39)
    let coordinate2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.13,76.69)
    // convert them to MKMapPoint
    let p1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate (coordinate2);
    let p2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate (coordinate1);

    let mapRect = MKMapRectMake(fmin(p1.x,p2.x), fmin(p1.y,p2.y), fabs(p1.x-p2.x), fabs(p1.y-p2.y));
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below function, which make the passed point center in map:

```
func centerLocationInMapView(centerPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    floatForRadiusInMiles = 10.0 // you can ignore this i have taken this for my custom radius property
    var scalingFactor: Double = abs((cos(2 * M_PI * centerPoint.latitude / 360.0)))
    var coordinateSpan: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(floatForRadiusInMiles / 69.0, floatForRadiusInMiles / (scalingFactor * 69.0))
    var coordinateRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerPoint, coordinateSpan)
    self.mapViewForHomeScreen.scrollEnabled = true
    mapViewForHomeScreen.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: TRUE)
    mapViewForHomeScreen.regionThatFits(coordinateRegion)
}
```

make a call to this function as

```
self.centerLocationInMapView( (first latitude + second latitude)/2 , (first longitude + second longitude)/2 )
```

> pass center point between two lat, long so that center will be map
>   center!

Comment: Using this I am definitely getting centre point but still map show the area around the center point not that coordinates.If i increase the radius it shows both the coordinates but i want the radius to be dynamic.

Comment: have you added the pins there on the respective coordinates?

Comment: No actually Pins are not there. I just want a rect of map between these two coordinates.

Comment: add pins to those coordinates, and adjust the map zoom level, so that that pins should get adjusted at map corners, then remove pins after getting the respective rectangle..!